# Parametrization of a hypocycloid

Tags: calculus, geometry, parametric

How do I prove that a hypocycloid, which has equation $$x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$$ can be parameterized by $$x = a\cos^3(\theta),\qquad y = a\sin^3(\theta)$$?

The problem assumes that it is true, but I'm not quite sure how to go about proving it. How do I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried substituting those values for $x$ and $y$ into the equation and checking that it works? Then you just need to think about how the different quadrants for $\theta$ give you the different quadrants for the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Upon substituting it in, you can quickly see that it is true.$$x^{\frac23}+y^{\frac23}=a^{\frac23}$$$$[a\cos^3(\theta)]^{\frac23}+[a\sin^3(\theta)]^{\frac23}=a^{\frac23}$$Distribute the exponents.$$a^{\frac23}\cos^2(\theta)+a^{\frac23}\sin^2(\theta)=a^{\frac23}$$Divide by $a^{\frac23}$.$$\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$$Which is a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the more general equation $x^p+y^p=r^p$ where $p>0$. Compare this to the identity $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$. Rewriting the first equation we have.

$$\frac{x^p}{r^p}+\frac{y^p}{r^p}=1$$

$$\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^p+\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)^p=1$$

$$\left[\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^{p/2}\right]^2+\left[\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)^{p/2}\right]^2=1$$

Using the trig identity

$$\left(\frac x r\right)^{p/2}=\cos(\theta)\quad\text{and}\quad\left(\frac y r\right)^{p/2}=\sin(\theta)$$

Solving for $x$ and $y$ we get

$$x=r\cos^{2/p}(\theta)\quad\text{and}\quad y=r\sin^{2/p}(\theta)$$
The hypocycloid is for the case $p=2/3$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you've only shown that the parametrization satisfies the equation. Why do you get the entire curve? Do you for all values of $p$?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to find two functions, $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, such that 
$$x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=f(t)^{\frac{2}{3}}+g(t)^{\frac{2}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}} \dots(1)$$
Then $f(\theta)=a \cos^3(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)=a \sin^3(\theta)$ give us
$$(a\cos^3(\theta))^{\frac{2}{3}}+(a \sin^3(\theta))^{\frac{2}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}}(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta))=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$$
So for that $f(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ it's a parametrization of the hypocycloide.
Note that $f$ and $g$ can be any functions that satisfy the condition (1)